# How to ignore project files in git but retain them when I clean

Tags: git, github

I am developing a project on github in visual studio (or intelliJ, the IDE doesn't matter) and I don't want to pollute the github repo with my project settings files. I know that I can ignore them but I do fairly regularly clean my project to remove all the generated js files to make sure it builds correctly from a clean checkout.

I see 2 potential ways to solve this. I can either ignore these files in some way that they won't get lost when I do a clean (I want to remove all my ignored js files when I clean though) or I can check the project files into my local repo but not deliver them somehow - that seems like a bit of a nightmare waiting to happen though with branches and partial commits and so on...

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't add these settings files to your `.gitignore`?

Comment: I can do but they will get removed when I clean my workspace.
I like to clean my workspace to test that it will all work for someone checking it out clean. (so I clean using x which removes ignored files)